# Relative and absolute paths issue using the include directive

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have the following `sphinx` directory structure for my project.

```
/applications
  /app1   
    Content.rst
  /app2
    Content.rst
/components
  /component1
    Content.rst
    /figures
       Figure1.png 
  /component2
    Content.rst
    /figures
      Figure1.png
```

For each reuseable UI software component I have a separate directory including some screenshots of the UI in figures. Every component has some figures, which makes directories easily moveable and re-namable, by using image directives using relative paths.

Furthermore, I have applications for our end user clients. But not every component is used in every application.

Now a problem with relative and absolute paths occurred. Assume that `applications/app1/Content.rst` contains somewhere:

```
.. include:: components/component1/Content.rst
```

Furthermore assume that `components/component1/Content.rst` contains somewhere:

```
.. image:: figures/Figure1.png
```

Now the file rst file of component1 is found an included in my documents, but the images of component1 are not included in the document.

Python Sphinx prints:

```
WARNING: image file not readable: figures/Figure1.png
```

Seemingly there is an issue with relative paths here, that I couldn't solve after trying for hours. I even still wonder what is the present working directory while processing `components/component1/Content.rst`.

I also want to avoid absolute paths in the `Content.rst` of the components if possible.

Any help for my problem is highly appreciated.

**Review**

If I change the image line to:

```
.. image:: components/component1/figures/Figure1.png
```

The image is displayed, but now I have a serious problem if I need to move or to rename my component.

But now I have another problem: In case someone wanted to include `components/component1/Content.rst` in the `index.rst` via the `toctree::` command. Then the images are looked at `components/component1/components/component1/figures/Figure1.png`, which is wrong again.

Comment: It's admirable that you've documented what you have tried and did not work, but I don't have a clear picture of what you are actually trying to accomplish. You want modularity, but you're not using modularity in your references. It's more complicated trying to account for things that you *might* need, not things that you actually must do. If you must use nested includes and image references, then use `../` to go up a directory. But by that point, you might as well use absolute references and call it soup.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need some time to overthink, what I actually wanted to accomplish. I'm now using the absolute references through my complete docs, because it was the only workable approach. But still sphinx issues a lot of image not found errors, but the result is correct. So I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I found it tragic that reST does not support root-relative paths like HTML does. I can not write something like `.. include:: /path` because there is not support for it. All paths must be relative - but I just hate `../../` in paths. It's ugly and unstable. I have a directory for files intended for inclusion and every inclusion has to use a different root-relative path. The only solution that comes to my mind is implementing reST plugin directive, with copy pasted code from their own include directive.